# dropdownlist item selected throw exception (stack empty)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I meet some problem with `Dropdownlist` item selected.

First ,  I add item into `Dropdownlist` then select item,but it always throw exception (stack empty) .

The exception says stack empty , but I had add new items in `dropdownlist`.

why I cant select ? In debug ,I saw it have 90 items in `dropdownlist`

My Code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dateDataBind();
            GetMemDetail();
        }
    }
    private void GetMemDetail()
    {
        var result = (from c in db.Customers
                      where c.CustomerID == thisCustomerID
                      select c).FirstOrDefault();

        //result.Birthday is '1990/5/10'
        //ddl_y item can't be selected, but ddl_m and ddl_d can
        ddl_y.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Year.ToString()).Selected = true;
        ddl_m.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
        ddl_d.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Day.ToString()).Selected = true;

    }
    private void dateDataBind()
    {
        for (int i = 1920; i < DateTime.Now.Year - 5; i++)
        {
            tempStr = i.ToString();
            ddl_y.Items.Add(new ListItem(tempStr + "Y", tempStr));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            tempStr = i.ToString();
            ddl_m.Items.Add(new ListItem(tempStr + "M", tempStr));
        }
        dateDayBind();
    }
    protected void dateDayBind()
    {
        ddl_d.Items.Clear();
        int mcount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_y.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddl_m.SelectedValue));
        for (int i = 1; i < mcount + 1; i++)
        {
            tempStr = i.ToString();
            ddl_d.Items.Add(new ListItem(tempStr, tempStr));
        }
    }
```

Expection throw:
System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
[image: Stack empty]

Comment: The code is running fine with a date 1990, 05, 10. There is no exception "Stack Empty" as far as I know, so can you please tell what is the actual exception when trying to select item in ddl_y ?

Comment: The stack empty exception occurs (as an invalid operation exception) when you try to pop an item from a Stack<T> for instance, which is not the case here..

Comment: Does the result have any records? How can you be sure about ddl_m ad ddl_d if you get an exception while selecting the item of ddl_y?

Comment: @OguzOzgul It gives error *Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList*

Comment: @OguzOzgul Because when I remark this line ,It work fine.

Comment: @nvartak yeh, I craet a new file , and it throw _Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList _ ... Its wired

Comment: No it's not. "1920" will be selected by default when you fill the drop down list. If you additionally set Selected = true on any other item, the drop down will throw this exception during Render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Stack Empty" error is caused by a Visual Studio design time feature I think. Probably not relevant.

The error message says it all. The drop down already has a different item (other than 1990) selected, and you are trying to select 1990 as well.

Try clearing the selection before selecting a new item. You might want to do this for the other drop downs as well:

```
ddl_y.ClearSelection();
ddl_y.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Year.ToString()).).Selected = true;
```

Comment: So that's how it is !  It's amazing , `Dropdownlist` have defualt selected items ! I've learnt a lesson (:

Comment: Actually, the <select> html element can have selectedIndex = -1 which means it does not have a selected item, but I think the asp.net DropDownList just does not support that for some reason. @LorenzoC

Comment: I think it supports it if you do ddl_y.SelectedItem = null;

Answer (score 1):

As per the execution flow, there is no selected value in the year and month drop down when the dateDayBind() method is called, so we should only try and populate the day section when year and month are already selected. The GetMemDetail() should looks like below:

```
private void GetMemDetail()
{
    var result = (from c in db.Customers
                  where c.CustomerID == thisCustomerID
                  select c).FirstOrDefault();

    //result.Birthday is '1990/5/10'
    //ddl_y item can't be selected, but ddl_m and ddl_d can
    ddl_y.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Year.ToString()).Selected = true;
    ddl_m.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
    dateDayBind();
    ddl_d.Items.FindByValue(result.Birthday.Value.Day.ToString()).Selected = true;

}
```

Don't forget to remove the call to dateDayBind() method inside dateDataBind() method.

Hope this will solve your problem.